# Google Sign In API - Additional Scopes (Gmail send as)

Tags: javascript, php, api, gmail

I'm implementing Google Sign In on my app.  Using their step by step guide located here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

For additional scopes, I'm doing this:

```
var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
                        {'scope': 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'});

googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
googleUser.grant(options).then(
            function(success){
                console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
            },
            function(fail){
                alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
            });
```

Evreything is working, but I'm confused on how to send email as the currently logged in user.  Do I need to ask Google for a refresh token? If so, how? I'm assuming I don't ask Google for refresh token since I've already authorized the scope.  How can I compose an email as the currently sign-in user?

Thanks,